# Specifying A Property As An Attribute Of Another Property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

So I have an EF class with two properties.

```
public class MyTable
{
    public DateTime Requested { get; set; }
    public Guid RequestedUserID { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to be able to insert the current User ID into `RequestedUserID` when Requested is changed.  To do this I can override EF's `DbContext.SaveChanges()` event and check if the any modified column has a given attribute instructing my code to also modify an associated `UserID` column.  Example attribute markup:

```
public class MyTable
{
    [TrackModifingUser(UserIDColumn = nameof(RequestedUserID))]
    public DateTime Requested { get; set; }
    public Guid RequestedUserID { get; set; }
}
```

And then later in my `DbContext.SaveChanges()` event I would get the property by name and set its value accordingly.

Issue, I wish my Attribute could store the property itself somehow.  And with that skip looking the property up by name.  Something like this.

```
public class MyTable
{
    [TrackModifingUser(UserIDColumn = RequestedUserID)]
    public DateTime Requested { get; set; }
    public Guid RequestedUserID { get; set; }
}
```

Is this possible or must I resolve the property at run time?  Is there any sort of caching I can use to avoid getting the property by name more than once for the same column?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, you want to label a specific field as the "Current User ID" field, and have DbContext.SaveChanges() automatically set that field to the value of the current user, if it's tagged. If that's correct, this is probably a good use-case for interfaces.

```
public interface ITracksCurrentUser
{
   Guid CurrentUserID {get;set;}
}

public class MyTable : ITracksCurrentUser
{
    public DateTime Requested { get; set; }
    public Guid RequestedUserID { get; set; }

    public Guid ITracksCurrentUser.CurrentUserID
    {
      get { return RequestedUserID;}
      set { RequestedUserID = value;}
    }
}

public override int SaveChanges()
{
   foreach(userentity in ChangeTracker.Entries().Select(e => e.Entity).OfType<ITracksCurrentUser>())
       userentity.CurrentUserID = Session["UserID"];
}
```

Comment: EF is merely an example use case.  The objective is to allow individual columns to specify each other in an attribute without the use `GetPropertByName` (or whatever the method name is.)